# Traceback (most recent call last) Odoo V-8 custom module

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am new to the Odoo development and i am currently trying to the learn the basics and came across a problem. I am working on the Odoo Version 8.

I am trying to install a diet facts module and i get the same error every time, i have tried switching browsers but to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>
    <record id= "dietfacts_product_template_tree_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
    <field name= "model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="categ_id" position="after">
            <field name="calories"/>
            <field name="servingsize"/>
            <field name="lastupdated"/>
            <field name="dietitem"/>
        </field>
    </field>
    </record>

    <record id= "dietfacts_product_template_form_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
    <field name= "model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="type" position="after">
            <field name="calories"/>
            <field name="servingsize"/>
            <field name="dietitem"/>
            <field name="lastupdated"/>
        </field>
    </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product.product_template_action_dietfacts" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Diet Items</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_sell":1, "default_dietitem":True}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to define a new product
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>


    <menuitem action = "product.product_template_action_dietfacts"
        id="menu_product_template_action_dietfacts"
        parent="base.menu_sales" sequence= "15"/>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 884, in search_read
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 905, in do_search_read
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 917, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5184, in search_read
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 1650, in search
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4687, in _search
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4498, in _where_calc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\osv\expression.py", line 662, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170901\server\.\openerp\osv\expression.py", line 830, in parse
ValueError: Invalid field u'categ.id.name' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'categ.id.name', u'=', u'Diet Items') on product_template (ctx: )>"
```

The above error persists even if i cleared my cookies, cache and changed browsers. I even tried to uninstall and install the module again. 
Is there something that i am missing? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in your posted code, but you have a filter domain anywhere on `product.template` which is wrong, maybe just a typo.

It should be `[('categ_id.name', '=', 'Diet Items')]`. `categ_id` is one of `product.template`s fields, and it has an underline instead of a dot.